# How to save a player's score and display it to other players?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a simple game where each player's score is stored in a database or server and you can see other player's scores and nicknames on the leaderboard.

It is not necessary that the score in the leaderboard be updated every second, I think an update every 10 minutes will be enough.
What is the simplest and cheapest solution to this problem?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using a database as you suggested?

Comment: @RufusL I'm new to this and don't know which one would be best for my purposes

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple choices (all of these are in a way free)

- Use a service like [PlayFab](https://github.com/PlayFab/UnitySDK) or another backend platform for games
- Use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) directly from unity
- Use your own HTTP API with a database. For example

  - Go and Postgresql (I made a [small API](https://gitlab.com/jesusnoseq/ld50/-/blob/master/main.go) during a game jam, the quality of the code is bad but you can get the idea)
  - AWS Lambda and DynamoDB (without provisioned capacity)